# Approximation with a rank-$1$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, norms, operator-norms

Given a matrix $A$ (generally speaking, complex and non-square), I want to find an identically-sized matrix $D$ with ${\rm rk} D\le 1$ to minimize the induced operator norm $\|A-D\|_2$. From the [Singular Value Decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) theorem, one can find $D$ with $\|A-D\|_2=\sigma_2(A)$ (the second singular value of $A$). Indeed, this is best possible: for any rank-$1$ matrix $D$, one has $\|A-D\|_2\ge\sigma_2(A)$.

- Is there any really simple proof of this last inequality?
- What is the name / reference for it?

(In fact, I was able to find a reference on the Web, but I'd like to double check it.)

Thanks!

Comment: [Eckart-Young-Mirsky Theorem](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379587901145).

Comment: Here's a proof: Say rank(D)=1. Then, there are $n-1$ vectors that span nullspace of $D$. Let $A=USV^T$. We can find a nonzero vector $z$ in null(D) $\cap V_2$, so $Dz=0$. Thus, $\|A-D\|^2 \ge \|(A-D)z\|^2 = \|Az\|^2 \ge \sigma_2^2$ ...

Comment: sorry for truncated notation: $A=USV^T$, and $V_k$ denotes the space spanned by the top-$k$ right singular vectors of $A$. Also, instead of "we can find a nonzero vector $z$...", I should have said: we can find a nonzero *unit* vector $z$; also, since $\|Az\|^2 = z^TA^TAz$, using $A=\sum_i \sigma_i u_iv_i^T$ the rest follows...

Comment: @Suvrit: this is not "a proof", this is *the* proof! Very nice!

Answer (score 3):

The proof can be found in Golub, van Loan's "Matrix Computations", Sec 2.